# Linked List error (Language: C)

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

The program should generate a graph and store its neighbours in an adjacency list. I get a `SEGFAULT` while parsing the list. It's so strange because when I try to access the list one by one, it works alright.

My code:

```
int main(void) 
{   

    typedef struct linkedList{
        int vertice;
        struct linkedList *next;
    }LL;

    typedef struct vertex{
        int color;
        int noOfNeighbours;
        LL *adj;
    }vertex;

    int E, V;

    scanf ("%d %d", &V, &E);
    //printf ("%d %d", E, V);

    int i, j; //loop variables

    vertex arrOfVertices [V];

    for (i=0; i<V; i++)
    {
        arrOfVertices[i].color=-1; 
        arrOfVertices[i].noOfNeighbours=-1;
        arrOfVertices[V].adj = NULL;
    }
    printf ("Output is : \n");
    int firstV, secondV;
    for (i=0; i<E;i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d %d", &firstV, &secondV);
        LL* temp = malloc (sizeof(LL));
        temp -> vertice = secondV-1;
        if (arrOfVertices[firstV-1].adj == NULL)
        {
            arrOfVertices[firstV-1].adj=temp;
            arrOfVertices[firstV-1].adj->next=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=arrOfVertices[firstV-1].adj;
            arrOfVertices[firstV-1].adj=temp;
        }
    }

    //Printing the list function. This part strangely segfaults and I don't know why
    for (j=0; j<V;j++)
    {
        LL* parser = arrOfVertices[j].adj;
     // printf ("%d : Color: %d\n", i+1, arrOfVertices[i].color);

        while (parser!=NULL)
        {
            printf ("%d\n", parser->vertice);
            parser = parser->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int firstV, secondV;   seems not initialized and no value assigned when used?

Comment: @Jerry_Y that `scanf()`, assuming it worked, should count for *something*.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, because the test case provides the value of E and it has exactly E lines then.

Comment: the value of V you input larger then 2?

Comment: @WhozCraig, exactly! That part works smooth as butter.

Comment: @WhozCraig , oh yes, now I see it

Comment: vertex arrOfVertices [V]; arrOfVertices[V].adj = NULL;  seems you are accessing out of index as well.

Comment: @DeveloperbyBlood if it does, consider yourself fortunate. Woe unto he that never checks the results of apis *the return validation results*. its a dreadful habit. stop it. Anyway, i'll keep reading.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'd this code in haste, was not worrying about exceptions then. Will make a note about it. Thanks for the concern :)

Comment: @AnishRamaswamy Exactly, Segmentation fault. Check the comment //Printing the list function, giving strange SegFault, don't know why, the error is in that part i.e. retrieval. (Edited the part, its j<V)

Comment: @DeveloperbyBlood oh i'm not concerned whatsoever, so long as *I'm* not running code written like that, but someday I may without knowing it. And did you read what Whoami commented? Its important (and I'll up vote it if he makes it an answer, though i'm suspicious there is more than just that).

Comment: @WhozCraig I read. But what it is doing is making the node value as NULL. Should it be a thing to worry? Because, for betterment, the node should be intialized to NULL initially.

Comment: It is directly exceeding the declared boundaries of the array indexes (0..V-1 for an array of size V) and in so doing invoking undefined behavior. it is imho a typo. It should be `arrOfVertices[i].adj = NULL; `

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks aton!!!!!! Seriously, so stupid error. Instead of `i`, i wrote a V there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was at `arrOfVertices[V].adj = NULL;`, it worked when changed to `arrOfVertices[i].adj = NULL;`. Typo Error. Phew! Thanks, @Whoami and @WhozCraig for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems you are wanting to define an array of size V, where the actual value of V is entered by the user. However, in C, the compiler needs to know the size of arrays in advance. C might let you place a type and variable declaration in any order, but that does not mean that this will be the order of execution.

If you must use an array, you need to set up a size of the array in advance, and check that it is large enough for the values entered. Or, you need to create a pointer to an Array of vertex. Then, after the user has entered V, you need to build as many structures as asked for by the user by using malloc and sizeof(vertex) as you(?) did in the later portion of the program.

p.s. As whoamI mentioned, you are also going to incur an out of bounds reference in line arrOfVertices[V].adj = NULL; Arrays in C are 0-based, so if V is 5, and you (by the methods above) generated 5 vertices, you must refer to the last vertex, as arrOfVertices[4].

Comment: The error was at `arrOfVertices[V].adj = NULL;`, it needed to be arrOfVertices[i].adj = NULL; Thanks, anyways :)